# How can I debug a Tcl 8.6 error in clock.tcl

Tags: tcl

In one of our NaviServer/OpenACS instances we often run into the following error. After a restart, the error is gone, but will reappear (under circumstances that I have not understood yet). It seems to me as if some code would mess up the message catalog or the locale used/seen by the clock.tcl implementation. However, I am unsure how to debug this best.

```
expected integer but got "GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE"
    while executing
"GetDateFields $clockval  $TZData($timezone)  GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE"
    (procedure "::tcl::clock::formatproc'%Y-%m-%dT%H\:%M\:%SZ'c" line 4)
    invoked from within
"$procName $clockval $timezone"
    (procedure "::tcl::clock::format" line 34)
    invoked from within
"clock format [clock seconds] -timezone :UTC -format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: What locale are you using? What is the output of `::msgcat::mclocale`?

Comment: The implementation of `clock format` is very complex (doing code generation at runtime) but the generated code is _mostly_ simple. Alas, in this case you're in a locale that appears to be missing the `GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE` information. What is your locale?

Comment: I have entered a log statement in the line directly above the line 744, which calls `set date [GetDateFields $clockval $TZData($timezone)  @GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE@]` that throws the error. The log statement outputs `[msgcat::mclocale]`, which was `en_us`. Hmmm

Comment: Unfortunately, the presumably correct response was deleted by the admins. Please un-delete it, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the problem sometimes happens, this rings a bell. The problem is likely to be caused by order of commands in the NaviServer/AOLserver blueprint that depends finally on the unpredictable order in hash tables. The change i have committed to the NaviServer source code repository on 2018-06-14 12:00 +0200 [#1](https://bitbucket.org/naviserver/naviserver/commits/38682f93b312f078fe03dc0dcf570a0d161a7deb) can probably avoid this problem, since it excludes everything from the ::tcl namespace from the blueprint. It has the disadvantage, that if a user adds content the ::tcl namespace, this will not be included in the blueprint.... but user should not do so.

Background: The order of serialization in the NaviServer blueprint depends for pure Tcl code on the (unstable) order obtained from the hash table, so it might not be always the same. If msgcat and clock are loading in an arbitrary order, the initialization these components can get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your nose is pointing into the right direction, I guess:

```
% package req msgcat
1.6.1
% ::msgcat::mclocale
de_at
% ::msgcat::mcset [::msgcat::mclocale] GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE 2299527 
2299527
% ::msgcat::mc GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE
2299527
% msgcat::mclocale dummy_locale
dummy_locale
% ::msgcat::mc GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE
GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE
```

However, `msgcat::mclocale` seems to get "corrupted" in a way that there is no matching catalog entry for key GREGORIAN_CHANGE_DATE. Alternatively, the namespace context might get borged (not impossible in NaviServer blueprinting). But, you need to first track down the output of `[msgcat::mclocale]` prior to failure (as suggested in an earlier comment). Even less likely, in some (actual) locale, the calendar transition has not been done yet and is missing from `clock.tcl` ;)

Comment: My first attempt of debugging would involve a custom [`msgcat:mcunknown`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/msgcat.htm#M17).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you :

```html
set milliseconds [clock clicks]
variable time [format "%s_%03d" [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y%m%d_%H%M%S] [expr {$milliseconds % 1000}] ]

puts $time
```